# How to make a discord bot that gives a role on a command

Tags: discord.js

I already know the basics like commands but I couldn't figure this out. I was looking at other answers and they didn't make sense. Here's my code (without the bot token in the `const token`):

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'token';
const PREFIX = '!';

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('This bot is online!')
})

bot.on('message', message => {
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'ping':
      message.channel.send('pong!')
      break;
  }
})

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this :

```js
switch (args[0]) {
  case 'role':
    var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "rolename");
    message.member.roles.add(role);
    break;
}
```

This example adds a role to the message author.

Comment: Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: What do I replace with my role?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I edited my example. Now the message author will get the role.